# Add More Parameters After WordPress Post Creation

Tags: wordpress, url

Once the wordpress post is published notice is displayed mentioning Post published. Likewise I need to pass a custom parameter in the URL and load a custom message according to the parameters

Is this possible ?

Default URL

/wp-admin/post.php?post=16&action=edit&message=6

What I want

/wp-admin/post.php?post=16&action=edit&message=6&custom_message=7